# Implementing slf4j logging in ear module

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, ear

I want to implement slf4j logging for a separate ear module, JBoss 6.1 is the AS. So far what i have tried is below
1. Adding below jars in my lib

```
slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

2. In all the classes done similar coding as below to get the logger:

   ```
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   //Class declarations
   private static final Logger LOG=LoggerFactory.getLogger(VMAddAccountCommand.class);
   ```

With this I am getting all the logs to the default servers log, **how can i configure it to pump the logs in a separate log file?**
Searching over stackoverflow, i found some solutions according to which i tried to create log4j.properties file in ear, but still the logs are going to same default location.

So, in short what i want to achieve is to pump the logs from my ear module to a separate log file, with the existing setup i.e. slf4j binding with log4j. Please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Create the log4j property file something like:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log/abc.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

In File specify the your custom path and load this property file in your main class.

Comment: Thanks Anand for the reply, actually there is no "main" class in the ear where i can load the property file. What i can think of now is the interceptor class which gets loaded initially. But, i am not sure if loading the config from this class would make the config available to all the other classes.